# How to get union typing in golang for shared fields?

Tags: go, polymorphism, software-design

I have a few classes that I'm importing that have some common fields.

```
package foo

type FooA struct {
    ...
    SharedVal int
}

type FooB struct {
    ...
    SharedVal int
}

type FooC struct {
    ...
    SharedVal int
}
```

For various reasons, I am unable to modify the `foo` package. I want to have some abstraction that gives me some sort of union typing so that I can create a setter for the `sharedVal` field; e.g. something like this

```
package bar

type GenericFoo = foo.FooA | foo.FooB | foo.FooC

func (f *GenericFoo) SetSharedVal(val int) {
    f.SharedVal = val
}
```

How do I do this? Interfaces don't work for me since they required shared methods, but the `Foo` classes don't have setters. It's preferrable that the solution doesn't involve importing other third-party packages since dependency management becomes complicated in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraint that you cannot modify the third-party package and there is no common interface method to leverage, your only alternative is to use the [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package to perform runtime inspection of any input values.

One such solution:

```
import "reflect"

// setSharedVal takes a pointer to a struct with a field 'SharedVal' of type int and sets it
func setSharedVal(v any, nv int) error {

    var rv reflect.Value

    if rv = reflect.ValueOf(v); rv.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return fmt.Errorf("must pass a pointer to struct")
    }

    if rv = rv.Elem(); rv.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return fmt.Errorf("must pass a pointer to struct")
    }

    const fieldName = "SharedVal"
    rv = rv.FieldByName(fieldName)

    switch rv.Kind() {
    case reflect.Invalid:
        return fmt.Errorf("struct has no field named %q", fieldName)

    case reflect.Int:
        rv.SetInt(int64(nv))
        return nil

    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("struct field %q must be of type %q", fieldName, reflect.Int)
    }
}
```

---

```
a, b, c := FooA{}, FooB{}, FooC{}

err = setSharedVal(&a, 1)
err = setSharedVal(&b, 2)
err = setSharedVal(&c, 3)
```

Output:

```
main.FooA{SharedVal:1}
main.FooB{SharedVal:2}
main.FooC{SharedVal:3}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/KwWyJBKpmiW